# Structures inside union

Tags: c, struct, unions

```
int main()
{
  union {
    struct {
      char c[2];
      char ch[2]; 
    } s;
    struct {
       int i;
       int j; 
    } st;
  } u = { (12, 1), (15, 1) };

  printf("%d %d ", u.st.i, u.st.j);
}
```

How come the above is printing "257 0"?

What difference is created by using `{}` instead of `()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `(12, 1)` and `(15, 1)` simplify to (oddly enough) `1`.  This is because, as Omkant said, you're using the comma operator, which executes each expression it divides, but returns the value of the final expression.  The [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) actually explains this pretty well.

As a result, `u.s.c[0]` gets filled with the first 1 and `u.s.c[1]` gets filled with the second 1.  Since a union overlays int `u.st.i` over `u.c[2]` and `u.ch[2]` (assuming 8-bit chars and 32-bit ints), and the architecture is little-endian (known from your result), you have a 1 in the lowest byte of `u.st.i` and a 1 in its second lowest byte, for a value of `256*1 + 1 = 257`.

Meanwhile, no values were written to the memory of `u.st.j`, so the 2nd output is 0.

Answer (score 14):

`{}` signifies initializing a sub-object.

`()` is an operator that groups an expression, e.g. `(1+3)*2`. You have confusingly used the comma operator, which discards its left-hand operand and returns the right-hand operand. `(12,1)` is the same as `1`.

Initializing a `union` always sets its first member and ignores the others. This is because only one member at a time can store a value.

Initializing an array subobject with a scalar value, as in passing `1` to initialize `c[2]`, automatically jumps into the array. This is called *brace elision*. The next `1` will initialize the second member of the array.

You assigned `1` to each of the chars in `c[2]`, and then read back the resulting byte string as a little-endian `int`. The array `ch[2]` was not explicitly initialized at all; in C++ it would be set to zero but I'm not entirely sure in C.

The initializer `{ {12, 1}, {15, 1} }` doesn't work because, apparently, brace elision interprets the  first `}` to close the entire `union`.

The initializer `{{ {12, 1}, {15, 1} }}` would avoid brace elision and set both arrays. `{ 12, 1, 15, 1 }` should do the same.

Note that the conversion between scalar values and byte strings is implementation-defined; in particular it depends on endianness and the size of `int`.

Comment: +1, but this `{ {12, 1}, {15, 1} }` doesn't compile with gcc -std=c99 error: extra brace group at end of initializer.

Comment: using u = { {12, 1}, {15, 1} }; is throwing error as below.error C2078: too many initializers

Comment: @user1915016 Sorry, I didn't try it. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
what the difference will it create if i use {} instead of ().
```

If you are using `()` then `,` will be `Comma operator` and the value assigned will the right- most value inside parenthesis.

But in case of `{}` `,` is `Comma seperator` and each individual value are assigned to corresponding members.But in this case it won't compile and throw an error :

`extra brace group at end of initializer.`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're misunderstanding the point of unions, objects in unions share their memory so you can only initialize one of the objects not both, in other words the underlying memory is the same, and as mentioned in the other answer initializing a union always sets its first member, so if you want to initialize the second member you can use C99 designated initializers:

```
u = {.st={15, 1} };
```

And to initialize the arrays in the first struct:

```
u = { .s={{12, 1}, {15, 1}} };
```

Or without `.s` for the first struct:

```
u = { {{12, 1}, {15, 1}} };
```

Comment: The intention seems to be: initialize the 2+2 characters, rather than initialize both structs. As it happens, structs and array initializer lists are both written with {}.

Comment: @Lundin but the printf prints the second struct, hence my answer.

Comment: @Lundin added an initializer for the first one too.